# Angular SPA, $rootScope variable does not trigger HTML update after page reload

Tags: angularjs, layout, single-page-application, rootscope

Scenario is a SPA Angular app.
I need to modify the Layout (hide/show stuff) whether I'm in a url path that needs a logged in user or not.
For that I have the following simple-layout class by default and is toggled as soon as isSimpleLayout is false.

```
<body class="simple-layout" data-ng-class="{'simple-layout' : isSimpleLayout}">
```

isSimpleLayout is part of the $rootScope and being set at the $routeChangeStart event like this:

```
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", (event, toState, toParams) => {

        if (toState.hasOwnProperty("$$route")) {
            var currentPath = toState.$$route.originalPath.toLowerCase();
            var routeRequiresLoggedInUser = doesRouteRequireLoggedInUser(currentPath);

            if (routeRequiresLoggedInUser) {
                if (!isUserLoggedIn()) { 
                    $rootScope.isSimpleLayout = true;
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $location.path("/authentication");
                } else {
                    $rootScope.isSimpleLayout = false;
                }
            } else {
                $rootScope.isSimpleLayout = true;
            }
        }
    });
```

This code works just fine, the only problem comes when I am in a path where I do need to be logged in, so isSimpleLayout is false and I reload the page (hitting F5), at this moment I debugged and isSimpleLayout is correctly being set to false, but somehow the HTML doesn't pick up the change and so the simple-layout class is still there.